# How do you get old values when validation fails in laravel and vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using laravel and vue and I want to retrieve the old values when validation fails but I can't get the old value because of the v-model I'm using in the select box...

```
<select id="role" name="role" class="form-control @error('role') is-invalid @enderror" v-model="roleType" value="{{old('role')}}">
     <option value="">Choose user role...</option>
     @foreach($roles as $role)
     <option value="{{ $role->name }}" {{ old('role', $role ) == $role->name ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $role->display_name }}</option>
      @endforeach
 </select>
```

My vue script

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:{
                roleType: '',
            },
        });
    });
```

is there a simple way of achieving this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of mix and match what you're currently doing with Vue + Blade. I think what you're looking for is to assign `roleType` (the Vue variable) with your old input which you get from pageload (so from PHP), because when you use `v-model` you're basically assigning the binding to that variable and you cant really assign the `value` as well.

`v-model` is basically a shorthand for `<some-element :value="myval" @input="myval = $event"`.

The way I usually solve this, is to have some sort of Form component which is initialized like so:

```html
{{-- some_blade_file.blade.php --}}
<form-component :init-form="@json(old())"></form-component>
```

Now, your form-component could look something like this:

```js
...
props: {
   initForm: Object,
}, 
mounted() {
   this.some_variable_in_this_component = this.initForm.some_old_value;
},
```

So the `init-form` serves as the initial state the Vue component is initialized with. You pass it to the component in your view file (that is where Blade's `@json` helper comes in handy; you can also just use `{{ json_encode(old()) }}`, it works mostly the same).